# preg_replace - How to remove <textarea cols="100"(...)> and </textarea>?

Tags: php

I got a *.txt file that contains html code. I want to remove:

```
<textarea cols="100" rows="50" name="newcontent" id="newcontent">
```

and

```
</textarea>
```

I'm able to remove first tag with this:

```
$content_replaced = preg_replace ("/<textarea cols=\"100\" rows=\"50\" name=\"newcontent\" id=\"newcontent\">/", "", $replace);
```

but can't figure out how to replace < /textarea> aswell.
Thanks :)

Comment: So you can replace `a` with nothing but cannot replace `b` with nothing? Because in that position I would first think about doing with `b` the same as I did with `a`.

Comment: You don't use regexes on HTML. Use DOM, and removal of a tag/element becomes trivial.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$content_replaced = preg_replace ("/<textarea cols=\"100\" rows=\"50\" name=\"newcontent\" id=\"newcontent\">.*?<\/textarea>/", "", $replace);
```

Basically, I just added .*? to your regexp. What that will do is it will "non-greedily" match all content up until the next closing  tag.

Comment: wouldn't this remove content between tags also?

Comment: Yep, I now assume that you only want to remove the end tag. Why not just do a second preg_replace, and simply match "</textarea>" and replace it with "" ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regexp. Here is example.

```
$string = "sdfsd <textarea cols=\"100\" rows=\"50\" name=\"newcontent\" id=\"newcontent\"> some text here </textarea>";
$result  = preg_replace("/.*?>(.*)<.*?>$/","$1",$string);
echo $result;
```

This will work only when You have only one tag in line.